# Handling Unicode in python 2.7 when saving string to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Dealing with Unicode is my only challenge programming with Python, I had many problems in my past project and I always brute forced my way out testing different encoding till something works (if there is any tutorial for beginners it will be very handy).

For example I have this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
string = "Åland Islands"
with open("1.txt","w")as f:
    f.write(string.decode("utf-8"))
```

Returning:

> ```
>    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

I tested many encoding to solve this with no luck.

Comment: string = u"Åland Islands", and then f.write(s), should work

Comment: didn't work
`  File "C:\Python27\learn\unicode\test.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file C:\Python27\learn\unicode\test.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coding line just tells the Python interpreter how *it* should interpret the bytes. That doesn't mean the script actually *contains* UTF-8-encoded text. In fact, the error message suggests that the file was saved as ISO-8859-encoded (Latin-1) text. 0xc5 is the Latin-1 encoding for Å; 0xc3 0x85 is the UTF-8 encoding.

You need to make sure your editor actually saves the file as UTF-8 encoded text, so that the coding line isn't lying to the interpreter.